# check multiple exceptions in python

Tags: python

Lets say I have:

```
 string = """{'prop1': 'foo' , 'prop2': [1,2,3], 'prop3': [12,3]} """

  def _validate_schema(blob):
    schema = {'prop1': str, 'prop2': list, 'prop3': list}
    if blob.keys() in schema.keys():
      for k, v in blob.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, schema[k]):
          continue
    raise ValueError("Bad schema: \
                      Expected: %s, \
                      Got: %s  \
                     " % (schema, blob))


   # Usage
   try:
      jsn = json.loads(string)
      _validate_schema(jsn)
   except ValueError:
     raise ValueError(' bad json format')
```

So basically, I want to raise appropriate ValueError.. but.. right now.. whatever is causing the issue i see 'bad json format' as exception..
And I dont want to have multiple try clauses??
is there a way to throw relevant string in same try clause.. ?

Comment: What would be a "relevant string"?

Comment: I don't understand your question as written, but I _think_ what you want is just `raise` by itself. With no args it reraises the exception with whatever text is already there. However, if you're not doing any extra code in your except clause this is totally pointless -- just don't catch the exception.

Comment: In other words, if your problem is that you're catching the exception and replacing the useful error message with something you put there, just stop doing that.

Comment: edited.. Though I think this will always throw exception in function as i am always raising the ValueError (fixing it.. )

Comment: The json module expects property names to be enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: @Jefe - There is no difference between `'property_name'` and `"property_name"` in python.

Comment: @DavidHammen. True - but irrelevant, since json's syntax is not the same as python's. The property names in `string` must be in double quotes to be valid json, as Jefe says. (PS: in fact, the `ValueError` message states exactly the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply replace your except statement by:

```
except ValueError as e:
    # do whatever to analyse e
    raise
```

Because raise will reraise the previous exception.

Comment: If you raise the error you caught straight away, **why bother catching it?!**

Comment: Not only is this pointless, it's wrong as you'll lose traceback information. Just don't catch it. If you want to log, then say `raise` to re-raise it properly. (Not `raise e`)

Comment: Clearly, he wants to catch it again. Maybe because it's a code simplification, and he wants to analyze the error before reraising it (maybe only in specific cases)

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting to catch an exception thrown by your schema checker, but you are actually getting an exception thrown by json itself before that.

In order to tell the difference, you will want to define the exception that your schema will raise.

Also note that json will probably return unicode, which will not agree with str in your check: isinstance(u"something", str)

```
import json

string = '{"prop1": "text", "prop2": [1,2,3], "prop3": [12, 3]}'
bad_json = "{'prop1': 'text'}"
bad_1 = '{"prop1": 42, "prop2": [1,2,3], "prop3": [12, 3]}'
bad_2 = '{"prop1": "text", "prop3": [12, 3]}'
bad_3 = '{"prop1": "text", "prop2": [1,2,3], "prop3": [12, 3], "extra": 0}'

class SchemaViolation(ValueError):
    pass

def _validate_schema(blob):
    schema = {'prop1': unicode, 'prop2': list, 'prop3': list}
    for key in blob.keys():
        if key in schema.keys():
            if not isinstance(blob[key], schema[key]):
                raise SchemaViolation("Bad schema: \
                      Expected: %s, \
                      Got: %s  \
                     " % (schema[key], blob[key]))
        else:
            raise SchemaViolation("key %s not allowed in schema" % key)

    for key in schema.keys():
        if key not in blob.keys():
            raise SchemaViolation("key %s is missing" % key)

# Usage
try:
    jsn = json.loads(string)
    _validate_schema(jsn)
    print 'success on good json string which matches schema'
except SchemaViolation as e:
    print 'false negative'
except ValueError as e:
    print 'json raised a ValueError because it was bad json: ', str(e)

try:
    jsn = json.loads(bad_json)
    _validate_schema(jsn)
    print 'should have failed in json'
except SchemaViolation as e:
    print 'should not get to here'
except ValueError as e:
    print 'json correctly raised a ValueError because it was bad json: ', str(e)


try:
    jsn = json.loads(bad_1)
    _validate_schema(jsn)
    print 'should have failed'
except SchemaViolation as e:
    print 'correctly detected schema error ', str(e)

try:
    jsn = json.loads(bad_2)
    _validate_schema(jsn)
    print 'should have failed'
except SchemaViolation as e:
    print 'correctly detected schema error ', str(e)

try:
    jsn = json.loads(bad_3)
    _validate_schema(jsn)
    print 'should have failed'
except SchemaViolation as e:
    print 'correctly detected schema error ', str(e)

print 'done'
```